# SSIS - Connection Manager Work Offline is grayed out

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to debug an SSIS package locally, but for some reason the connection manager is offline and it can't be changed.

Have anyone faced this issue before and how did you solve this?

Here are some additional information:

1. Visual Studio Enterprice 2019
2. SQL Server Integration Services - 15.0.2000.123

[image: x]

Comment: If you edit the connection manager, and test the connection, does this change anything?
Are you using integrated security or username/password? Whats the package encryption level wan using username/password?

Comment: Hi Preben, I did edit the connection manager and the test connection is successful, but it's still grayed out. I am using integrated security.

Comment: I just noticed this happened to my packages - they were working yesterday. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: I am having the same issue were you able to figure out a fix? I can hit test connection and it works but the connection manager is offline and the work offline when i right click is grayed out...

Answer (score 2):

Belatedly providing the solution just in case anyone else comes across this issue.
The solution is to uncheck 'work offline' from the SSIS menu, under extensions, on Visual Studio.

[SSIS Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITUw0.png)